# Business Language for "Good looking out"

Tags: phrase-requests, slang, business-language

I am looking for a business language alternative to the slang "[good looking out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+lookin%27+out)" meaning something similar to "thanks for looking out for me" but with a more familiar tone appropriate for use with a colleague. Some versions I've kicked around:

- "Thanks for looking out for me" - Too formal, seems like this person is a guardian or overseer to my work and not really appropriate for a colleague.
- "Good catch, thanks" - It's not really a catch, so much as them giving advance notice of something that could be an issue. They're catching an issue sure, but it's not so much a "catch" as much as it is a warning of possibility.
- Simply, "thanks" - I'd like my coworkers to be a bit more open with me than just a "thanks" to end the conversation. I'd like it to be a collaborative effort to keep the team going, so a droll "thanks" does't seem to do the trick.

**What is a good business alternative for the slang "good looking out"?**

Comment: *You got my back, thanks.*

Comment: Thanks for covering (for) me.

Comment: I disagree that your first option is too formal and connotes a guardian or overseer relationship.  A coworker can definitely “lookout” for a coworker.  And any use of “looking out for” is informal to start with.

Comment: “Thank you for catching that” thanks someone for a specific action without getting tangled up in the relationship. Anyway, there’s  website for that. Take it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Much appreciated" is a slightly more formal way to express thanks than "good lookin' out".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few versions, but to begin with, "appreciate" and other forms of this word are definitely more formal than "thanks."
Secondly, if you are working toward building a more intimate relationship with your team with heartfelt gratitude, you could probably use some words that convey collectiveness and teamwork, such as "support", "cooperation", "care", and "collaboration."

Finally, it seems like you are thanking your colleagues for teaming up with you during a sticky situation and dealing with it together. It would be nice to mention that they indeed helped you.
In the end, piecing that together yields this template that works from my experience:

All of your [insert collectiveness and teamwork words such as support and/or cooperation and/or care and/or collaboration] during difficult times like this one [insert the problem and how they have indeed helped you] is greatly appreciated. I look forward to working together again.

If you want a really short phrase, try: "I appreciate you bailing me out" or "Your watchfulness and care for me is much appreciated."